# Redirect to a time out page using asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

What is the proper way to configure a time out page, that is automatically redirect to when session expires and an authorized page is accessed?

I´m setting my session time out like this:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure cookie name:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
  options.CookieName = ".MyProjectName.Session";
  options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
});
```

And try with following attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class CheckSessionOutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Session != null)
        {
            if (context.Session.IsNewSession)
            {
                string sessionCookie = context.Request.Headers["Cookie"];

                if ((sessionCookie != null) && (sessionCookie.IndexOf("MyProjectName.Session") >= 0))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                    string redirectTo = "~/Account/Login"; //YOUR LOGIN PAGE HERE
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.RawUrl))
                    {
                        redirectTo = string.Format("~/Account/Login?ReturnUrl={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.RawUrl));
                        filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectTo);
                        return;
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[CheckSessionOut]
public ViewResult Index()
{
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dawid, this is for asp.net core?